# "This transaction cannot be processed. The merchant's account is not able to process transactions."

Tags: paypal, transactions

We are working on getting a new website up. Clients are supposed to be able to make purchases with their credit cards through Paypal, but it keeps giving the error: "This transaction cannot be processed. The merchant's account is not able to process transactions."

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1147&actp=LIST

Answer (score 2):

This is because mainly your account does not supported for the API you use. Probably you are using DoDirectPayment or credit card transactions in REST API without having a permission from PayPal.